Is there a way to use variables or code in ssh config?
Imagine you have X sites and each site has a naming schema they use for proxy access. I'd like to create an ssh config file that would satisfy all X sites but not duplicate my ssh config.
For example, if I'm at an ssh host at site A I want the ssh config file to derive that it's on a site A host by taking the first 3 characters of the host name. this is a dummy config file, but only site A hosts can access site A hosts. only site B for site B... etc. instead of having 4 entries I'd like to just use 2.
Host siteA*-worker
    ProxyCommand ssh -qxT -At siteA_security nc %h %p

Host siteA*-worker2
    ProxyCommand ssh -qxT -At siteA_security nc %h %p

should be something like
Host $(hostname | cut -c1-2)*-worker
    ProxyCommand ssh -qxT -At $(hostname | cut -c1-2)_security nc %h %p

Host $(hostname | cut -c1-2)*-worker2
    ProxyCommand ssh -qxT -At $(hostname | cut -c1-2)_security nc %h %p


your description doesn't match your code - you say you have 4 entries but the code only shows two. additionally, the two shown could trivally be turned into one since the proxy commands are identical

depending on specific details, you might be able to use Match exec instead of Host. And your ProxyCommand can be a shell script that ends up calling ssh

also cut -c1-2 does not extract the first 3 characters.

4 entries would be siteB entries duplicated.  i just used a small example at the end to show you it cut down to 2 entries.   and yeah i mistyped the cut command, buts still works as a point.....  Match isn't going to work.  i'd still have to have multiple entries instead of the config file knowing what it should be

you realise that Match exec could run the commands you are trying to fit into Host ? If it won't work, add examples to the question that demonstrate why

you cut 2 entries down to 2 entries, which could have been a single entry to begin with. you need to provide better examples, otherwise people won't be able understand the problem
